# application doesnt launch

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I have some error with my android project and eclipse, when I start the emulation it fails:

[image]

I think its a problem with eclipse, because it worked yesterday but today I have this error.

I have no more information, the console has nothing ando so does the LogCat.

I tried to clean the project, but the error continues.

How can I solve this?

Comment: can you post the error log?

Comment: checkk AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: Tamilarasi Sivaraj, I can't post the error log, as I said in the post, it's empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Task manager kill adb.exe

and relaunch the eclipse

And than clean project.

Answer (score 1):

Go to cmd, type following command:

```
adb kill -server

adb start server
```

then run program, surely it is working.